# Check if javascript object contains some of gives keys

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object of around 10 Arrays. And I want to check if objects contains one of the 2 arrays. ( I know the names of arrays that server returns)

```
data.serverObjects = {
  cityNames : [],
  cityCodes: [],
  cityMapData: []
}
```

I'm trying to achieve below results:

```
data.serverObject.hasOneOfKey('key1', 'key2')  //should return false
data.serverObject.hasOneOfKey('cityNames', 'key2')  //should return true
```

I wanted to do it by using  `_.findKey` , but i use version 1.6 of `underscore` which doesn't support this function.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Is [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) what you're looking for?

Comment: I have more than one properties to be looked into.

Comment: Then using `Object.prototype.keys` and `hasOwnProperty` you can write a function doing just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm fan on underscore, I came up with below solution. Please suggest if this looks good.

Given object is,

```
var serverObjects = {
  cityNames: [],
  cityCodes: [],
  cityMapData: []
}
```

**Solution:**

```
var serverObject = _.keys(data.serverObject);
var hasOneOfKey = _.any(serverObject, function (property) {
    return (property.indexOf('cityNames') !== -1 || property.indexOf('key') !== -1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over keys and check with `hasOwnProperty`:

```
Object.prototype.hasOneOfKey = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(arguments[i])){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: I up-voted you answer. Please suggest if my solution also looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional solution:

```
Object.prototype.hasOneOfKey = function(keys){
    return Object.keys(this).filter(function(d){
        return keys.indexOf(d) >= 0;
    }).length > 0;
}
```

Example:

```
var person = {
    name: "Bart",
    surname: "Simpson"
};

person.hasOneOfKey(["name","age"]); // true
person.hasOneOfKey(["age"]);        // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

**P.S:** This works with only 2 values in the function `hasOneOfKey`

```js
var serverObjects = {
  cityNames: [],
  cityCodes: [],
  cityMapData: []
}

Object.prototype.hasOneOfKey = function(a, b) {
  return (a in this || b in this);
}

console.log(serverObjects.hasOneOfKey('key1', 'key2'));

console.log(serverObjects.hasOneOfKey('key1', 'cityNames'));
```